# Only get the row with the highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data (Link 1) and I expect the result (Link 2) [only get the row with the highest value of "Revision" Column if "Serial" Column are same] as following:

[Link 1] : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3CWy.png]

[Link 2] : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCkI2.png]

Anyone can help me solve this issue ? I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not post pics of your data and structure post table structures and data examples.  Plus what have you tried?  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can give a shot to Row_Number with Partition as shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Brad : I will not upload the data image next time. Thank you for the reminder

Comment: @emoreau99 : Thanks your link and I will check method 2 of Popeye also mentions to row_number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `not exists` as follows:

```
Select t.*
  From your_table t
 Where not exists
       (Select 1 from your_table tt
         Where tt.serial = t.serial and tt.revision > t.revision)
```

Or you can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by serial order by revision desc) as rn
  From your_table t) t
 Where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi Popeye,
I have checked method 1 and it works. I will check method 2 now.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Method 2 works. Thank you very much Pepeye

Comment: You can accept the answer if it resolved your issue